# i want to disallow all of the special characters except for normal letters( a- z) but not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, validation

i have textboxes like username firstname lastname password contact etc. i want to have these textboxes to only accept letters a-z and avoid all of the special characters. i have this line of code from the username textbox:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtUser" runat="server" name="form-first-name" placeholder="Username..." class="form-first-name form-control"></asp:TextBox>
                                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" 
                    ErrorMessage="User name is required." ControlToValidate="txtUser" 
                    ForeColor="Red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                    <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator2" runat="server" 
                                        ErrorMessage="Invalid Username" ControlToValidate="txtUser" ForeColor="Red" 
                                        ValidationExpression="[a-zA-Z]"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

but everytime i typed in letters, its giving me the error mesasge i implemented? really confused. hope you guys can help me on this. thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define that the text goes from the start to the end of the string with the `^` and `$` characters. You also need to specify the number of times to match the pattern by using a quantifier. (Use `+` for once or more, or `*` for 0 or more)

```
ValidationExpression="^[a-zA-Z]+$"
```

Comment: one more question sir. i have the regex as mentioned above ^[a-zA-Z]+$ but in the email textbox, i want to allow the @ character.

Comment: Try something like `^.+\@.+\..+$`. There are a lot of email regexes out there but that works pretty good.

Comment: Or just `[a-zA-Z@.]`.

Comment: ok i will :) is it following the first regex?  ^[a-zA-Z]+ ^.+\@.+\..+$ like this?

Comment: No, you replace the entire thing with that. If you just want the @ and . character, go with the second one.

Comment: thank you so much sir. last question hehe what about letters and numbers only? i  tried "^[a-zA-Z]+$ ,[0-9]*$" but not wrking?

Comment: That would make letters, then numbers (without the junk in the middle). Put them into a single group like `^[a-zA-Z0-9]$`

Comment: thank you! so in the other textboxs i want to add the number letter and @ it should be somrthing like this. ^[a-zA-Z@.0-9]$